# Promoted Links based on Permission Sets or Ad Group

Tags: security-trimming, promoted-links

I have a list of promoted links (tiles), around 60, and depending on the AD Group a user is associated with, he/she will have access to just one area (so one promoted link will work for him) and not others. However, when the person gets to the landing page, ALL of the promoted links are shown and if the user clicks on a link that he has no access to, then he'll get a message saying he has no access. This is bad design since if the person doesn't know where he has access, he has to keep clicking until he finds the right tile. I'm just trying to display what he/she is supposed to see. How could I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: have you already tried to apply custom permissions / trimming on the items in the source list for the promoted links? You didn't state that so I will leave this as a comment for now (and maybe convert it to answer later if needed). While SharePoint won't analyze the urls you are promoting to decide if some should be "trimmed out" (from a design perspective, you could as well have included urls that are external to SharePoint in the first place), it should still enforce whatever visibility the items in the source list it is enumerating define.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Thanks for the answer, you mentioned "apply custom permissions / trimming on the items in the source list for the promoted links" , honestly I'm not sure how this is accomplished - I could go so many ways on this way. Any hits? THank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the user/group permission on the **list item level** in the `Promoted list` as the following :

- Go to site contents > open your list > click on `All Promoted Links` view
- Now the items should be shown like all items normal list.
- Select the items that you need to show for a specific people.
- From the above ribbon > Item tab > select `Shared With` .

[image]

- Click on Advanced  to open permission settings for this list item.
- Stop Inheriting permission , and set only the users and group that you need to show this link.

Now the links should be shown only based on the user item permission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get an error saying: "This Control is currently disabled". I should have full permission/access level. Is there a setting I need to change? Thanks again

Comment: Glad you found my comment useful, at least I won't have to lose time converting it in an answer since you already did it for me.

Comment: Dear @SPArchaeologist your comments / answer always useful :) , and I really repect you, but I found the question owner ask for How he can do this at his comment for you,  and  because I did this before at  my site , I post my answer to help him quiclly and with more details  so I am sorry if you feel somthing else where our aim is one (help people) :)

Comment: @LearnByReading , this is not considered an error , this mean you don't have a sufficient permission to do that , so ask your site administrator to do this , or give you sufficient permission to can manage this permission . by going to site setting > user permission >  site permission > set your permission as full control , or at least give yu full control for  this permission to can manage permission . please don't hesitate to ask for more clarification

Comment: @M.Qassas I actually have full permission/access. I am the site admin, but I still get that message!

Comment: @LearnByReading , are you sure you select the item that you need to provide it with custom permission , also should you check if you face this issue with other lists :)